# Type problems with Doubles in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I wanted to implement this sum. I ran into problems regarding type signatures.

[image]

This is how it looks like in Haskell.

```
crowdWrong :: (Fractional b, Integral b) => b -> b
crowdWrong m = crowdWrong' m m

crowdWrong' :: (Fractional b, Integral b) => b -> b -> b
crowdWrong' m 1 = ((0.49) ^ (m-1)) * (0.51) * (choose m 1) * (0.98)
crowdWrong' m i = ((0.49) ^ (m-i)) * ((0.51) ^ i) * (choose m i) * (0.98)
                  + (crowdWrong' m (i - 1))

choose :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
choose n 0 = 1
choose 0 k = 0
choose n k = (choose (n-1) (k-1)) * n `div` k
```

The output of GHCi is:

```
untitled.hs:5:55:
    Could not deduce (b ~ Integer)
    from the context (Fractional b, Integral b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 crowdWrong' :: (Fractional b, Integral b) => b -> b -> b
      at untitled.hs:(5,1)-(7,42)
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            crowdWrong' :: (Fractional b, Integral b) => b -> b -> b
          at untitled.hs:5:1
    In the first argument of `choose', namely `m'
    In the second argument of `(*)', namely `(choose m 1)'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely
      `((0.49) ^ (m - 1)) * (0.51) * (choose m 1)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I have no Idea how to fix this, i imagined this to be a lot easier.

EDIT:

So now i have this:

```
crowdWrong :: Num b => Integer -> b
crowdWrong m = crowdWrong' m m

crowdWrong' :: Num b => Integer -> Integer -> b
crowdWrong' m 1 = ((0.49) ^ (m-1)) * (0.51) * (choose m 1) * (0.98)
crowdWrong' m i = ((0.49) ^ (m-i)) * ((0.51) ^ i) * (choose m i) * (0.98)
                 + (crowdWrong' m (i - 1))

choose :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
choose n 0 = 1
choose 0 k = 0
choose n k = (choose (n-1) (k-1)) * n `div` k
```

GHCi still complains, though.

```
untitled.hs:5:48:
    Could not deduce (b ~ Integer)
    from the context (Num b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 crowdWrong' :: Num b => Integer -> Integer -> b
      at untitled.hs:(5,1)-(7,42)
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            crowdWrong' :: Num b => Integer -> Integer -> b
          at untitled.hs:5:1
    In the return type of a call of `choose'
    In the second argument of `(*)', namely `(choose m 1)'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely
      `((0.49) ^ (m - 1)) * (0.51) * (choose m 1)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Hint: use http://mathurl.com/ to render TeX math.

Comment: Sometimes it is worth remembering that Haskell can infer the types on its own (unless fancy extensions are used), and will infer the most general type. Hence, when in doubt, comment out the type signatures and ask ghci what type it is.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is basically right, but the types you've requested for the various pieces don't match.

1. `choose` must take and return `Integer`s.  This is OK on its own, but…
2. `crowdWrong'` must be able to take and return *any* type `b` that's both a `Fractional` and an `Integral`.  `Integer` is only one concrete type (and isn't an instance of `Fractional`, to boot).  This it the error you're getting: the `~` is how Haskell spells type equality, so "Could not deduce `(b ~ Integer)`" means that `b` ≠ `Integer`.  Note that this is unlike Java and other OO languages; a type signature such as `crowdWrong' :: (Fractional b, Integral b) => b -> b -> b` means that `crowdWrong'` must be able to take and return *any* such `b`, not *some* such `b`.  (It's called *parametric polymorphism*, and it's like generics/templates.)

   This error is biting you twice.  The first problem is that `choose` expects `Integer` arguments, but you've passed it `m` and `i`, which are of the arbitrary type `b`.  The simplest fix here is just to make `m` and `i` `Integer`s, which seems (looking at the equation) to be correct anyway.  The only other place you use `m` and `i` is as the exponent with `(^)`, which has type `(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a`.  In other words, `(^)`'s left and right sides don't need to have the same type.

   The second problem is that `choose` returns an `Integer` result, but you're multiplying it by fractional numbers.  You can fix this by using `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`, which allows you to build any kind of `Num`ber out of an `Integer`.  So instead of `choose m 1`, you can write `fromInteger (choose m 1)` (or, to be fancy, `` fromInteger (m `choose` 1) ``; the backticks allow you to write any function infix).  And this will even compile!  However…
3. There are no types which are both `Fractional` and `Integral`, so you won't be able to *call* these functions.  The `Fractional` type class is for rational-number-like things, whereas the `Integral` type class is for integer-like things.  (This is why `Fractional` has `(/)`, and `Integral` has `quot`/`div`.)  Usually, if you see those combined in your type signature, you have a conceptual type error.  Luckily, this is easy to fix; since `m` and `i` are now `Integer`s, you can get rid of the `Integral` constraint and just have `Fractional` (and this is what Haskell will infer for you).

So all told, you end up with the new code

```
crowdWrong :: Fractional a => Integer -> a
crowdWrong m = crowdWrong' m m

crowdWrong' :: Fractional a => Integer -> Integer -> a
crowdWrong' m 1 = (0.49 ^ (m-1)) * 0.51 * fromIntegral (m `choose` 1) * 0.98
crowdWrong' m i = (0.49 ^ (m-i)) * (0.51 ^ i) * fromIntegral (m `choose` i) * 0.98
                  + (crowdWrong' m (i - 1))

choose :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
choose n 0 = 1
choose 0 k = 0
choose n k = ((n-1) `choose` (k-1)) * n `div` k
```

(I took the liberty of removing some redundant parentheses and switching to infix form for `choose`.)

This doesn't seem to quite correspond to your sum, though: I think you should have `` crowdWrong m $ m `quot` 2 ``, and `i` should bottom out at `0` instead of `1`.  And the repetition in `crowdWrong'` is annoying.  You can instead write your code as a literal `sum`, and thereby avoid the manual recursion.

```
crowd :: Fractional a => Integer -> a
crowd m = sum [ 0.49^(m-i) * 0.51^i * fromIntegral (m `choose` i) * 0.98
              | i <- [0 .. m `quot` 2] ]
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  You edited your post with an update that doesn't compile, but it looks like that was before my answer.  If everything's working, and I or [chaosmasttter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17456789/237428) have answered your question, [you should consider "accepting" the appropriate answer by clicking on the green check mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/140878).  If something isn't working, could you clarify what problems you're still having?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your are using the false types. First you cannot have a type `b` which is a `Fractional` and a `Integral` at the same time, but that is what you want `b` in `crowdWrong` and `crowdWord'` to be. Instead you should use `Num b` as  context.
The problem your compiler is complaining about is, that you explicitly said `choose` gets two `Integer` arguments, but in `crowdWrong'` you give it an argument of type `Num b => b`. You should change the type signature of `crowdWrong'` to `Num b => Integer -> Integer -> b` and the type of `crowdWrong` to `Num b => Integer -> b`.